# Integration quickbooks online button in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, authorization, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

How to use QBO connect button with AngularJs?
I'm trying to add QuickBooksOnline connect button to the page with AngularJs. I had created directive like that: https://gist.github.com/ahey/14f75186674a5fdac318
when user clicks on the button - new browser window opened, but immidiately after this redirected to the grant url (authorization page skipped). Code is very simple:

```
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <connect-to-quickbooks />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are already signed into QBO via browser session. In that case, I believe you go right to the callback.

Also, I am assuming you have a valid grant url sending a consumer request token e.g.

```
"https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/Begin?oauth_token=#{request_token}"
```

UPDATE:
Here is an alternative directive: http://minimul.com/connect-to-quickbooks-angular-directive.html

Comment: do you think it's possible to integrate with QuickBooks Online with pure Angular, no need to node.js/rails or any backend?

Comment: @Minimul, Here I am using your angular-directive for open pop-up, its working properly, can told me now how can I close window after save token ?